# How to import a class in vim on python?

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to import the pyperclip class for python on the vim text editor on the mac terminal. I have simply typed `import pyperclip` in the text editor, and I even wrote the command `:py import pyperclip` in the actual running area outside of the editor. The error I get is a traceback error because it cannot find any module named pyperclip. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: have you install pyperclip yet?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: Just as an update, after Carlos' comment I double checked to make sure pyperclip was installed and found that it was installed in a location that was different than what I told the computer. After a few trials, I was finally able to get it to work. Thanks :)